# java value object

Tags: java, value-objects

I'm new to Java and I have to create a value object, (maybe it's called mapped object in Java) but my code doesn't seem to work, here is the value object:

```
package ....;

public class User {
    private int id;    
    private int uid;    
    private String name;

    public User()
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

and I assign a new value object like this:

```
public boolean some_function() 
{               
    User u = new User();

    return true; // got a breakpoint here
}
```

So if I comment out "User u = new User();" I will go to the breakpoint but if I keep it like above it will just stop running.

On a side note, I keep both the files in the same folder so eclipse doesn't import the file, is this correct or should I import it?

**EDIT:**

After some time I found out that I had to import the file manually, I thought I tried that but apparently I didn't.

Comment: You are not providing enough details to say anything. What do you mean mean by stop running? Can you see any error? What are you doing in the `User()` constructor? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dennis, if the code as you posted it is the exact code you're running, then this makes no sense -- the "User u = new User();" call would return you a new User object without any issues, since your constructor is empty.

To demonstrate that to yourself, change your constructor to:

```
public User() {
  System.out.println("I'm inside the User constructor!");
}
```

and call your some_function() function again.  You should see that line printed out to your console.

Given what you're reporting and the code you're showing, I suspect that the class that contains some_function() isn't "seeing" the User class -- you're importing some other User class rather than the one you created.  Are the two classes -- the User class and the class which contains some_function() -- in the same package?  If not, what import statement at the top of the some_function()-containing class is handling the import of your User class?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you don't have an infinite loop in your User() constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Put some code into the constructor, for example

```
id = 99;
```

set a break point there.

I don't understand what you mean about importing into Eclipse - I have all my code in Eclipse - however I suspect that your application is not correctly seeing the User class. Maybe you are even getting a compilation error. Create your packages and classes in Eclipse, let it sort out the directories for you.

Show us the whole app class , including the import of User.

Answer (score 0):

Put the breakpoint on `User u = new User();` and step into the constructor to see what it's doing.